Steps to turn an integral over a circle smoothed by a Gaussian into modified Bessel functions
I used sympy to find that an integral I need,
$$
P(\xi) = \int_{0}^{\infty}dr\ \frac{e^{-(r+\xi)^2}}{\sqrt{r}}
$$
can be expressed in terms of modified Bessel functions as
$$
\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}({\scriptstyle\frac12}z)^{1/4}e^{-z}\big(I_{-\frac14}(z) - {\rm sgn}(\xi)I_{\frac14}(z)\big)\quad\mbox{with}\quad z\equiv{\scriptstyle\frac12}\xi^2
$$
I verified this numerically (indeed, that was how I determined the need for ${\rm sgn}(\xi)$), but even knowing the answer, I cannot figure out how to go from my expression to one of the integral representations of the modified Bessel functions (unfortunately, sympy's manual_integration.integral_steps does not show anything for this integral).  Does anybody know? E.g., what typical substitutions one should do? Or how to express it in a relevant series?
p.s. For context, I have a density distribution that peaks on a circle, i.e., $\rho(r) = \rho(R) e^{-\frac{1}{2}((r-R)/\sigma)^2}$, and I want to calculate the column density as a function of $x$, i.e., evaluate
$$
I(x) = \rho(R) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy\ e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-R)^2/\sigma^2}
$$
The integral above follows from a change of variable to $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and then making the integral dimensionless.

A similar result appeared on this site recently here. Indeed, the substitution $u=\sqrt{r}$ may be enough to convert your integral into that form.

@Semiclassical - indeed, the accepted answer has everything, thanks!! The Parabolic Cylinder function is quite appropriate, since the structure we are actually considering is a cylindrical filament of cold matter with a skin that is becoming ionized, and we want the electron column density through it.
